# Dúvida sobre a estrutura do projeto doctrine\dbal

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine

Li a [Documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) a única coisa que não entendi, foi como é a estrutura dele.

Explico:

Meu arquivo `composer.json` na raiz do projeto

```
{
 "require": {
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*"
  }
}
```

Ao executar o comando:

```
php composer.phar install
```

ele baixa as dependências gerando a pasta `vendor` ok. Mas são muitos arquivos que de acordo com a documentação são desnecessários. Veja na imagem meu projeto: 
[image: Meu projeto]

Quero entender a estrutura desse projeto pelo que andei lendo a única parte importante é a `\lib\DBAL` as demais não precisa. É isso mesmo. E em relação ao projeto queria usar assim. Ter uma pasta `\class` e dentro colocar os arquivos tanto do `doctrine\dbal` quanto as classes `bootstrap.php` e `crud` (seria `crud.php` com as funções de CRUD e um `require(bootstrap.php)` o Bootstrap é onde estaria a conexão com o banco). E fora da pasta `class`(raiz do projeto) fazer a chamadas das funções em minhas paginas. É como faço em um projeto normal.

Estou fazendo esta pergunta porque não encontrei nada na internet que fale a respeito deste assunto nem na documentação. Estou iniciando no `doctrine\dbal`, desculpa se estou sendo incompreensível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está fazendo isso quase do jeito certo.

Quando você instala uma dependência no seu projeto, não raramente ele costuma ter outras dependências. No caso do `doctrine/dbal`, como você poder ver no [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal) (ou diretamente, no próprio [repositório](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal)), uma das dependências dele é o pacote `doctrine/common`.

O Doctrine já é uma biblioteca que tem vários anos de amadurecimento, então é um tanto óbvio que ele não consista de apenas um ou poucos arquivos. Entretanto, com o gerenciamento de dependências cada vez mais fácil, isso não deveria ser problema, já que as dependências ficam na pasta `vendor/` e o seu código fica na raiz do projeto (em geral, a pasta `vendor/` não deve ser comitada, e sim, seus arquivos `composer.json` e `composer.lock`).

Fiz um pequeno projeto aqui, e a estrutura ficou assim:

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "root/teste-dbal",
    "require": {
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.x-dev"
    }
}
```

autoload.php:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');

// prepara a conexao
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$connectionParameters = [
    'dbname'      => 'cms',
    'user'        => 'root',
    'password'    => '',
    'host'        => 'localhost',
    'driver'      => 'pdo_mysql',
    'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'
];
$connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParameters, $config);
```

crud.php

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php');

// executa a query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Se aparecer mais alguma dúvida, é só falar. :)

Comment: Blz.
Estou tentando fazer uma coisa para imprementar esses conhecimentos nele,
Valeu, duvidas posto sim.

Comment: E aí, deu certo? Se sim, não esqueça de validar a resposta. :)

Comment: Estou testando sim. Valeu acredito que vai funcionar, vou impremeta-lo.
Como valida a resposta aqui? eu não sei como validar.

Comment: É só marcar com um "ok" perto do início da resposta, do lado esquerdo.